# Ich habe bei oder von euch gekauft?

Tags: word-choice

> Ich habe die Sachen bei euch (dir, ihnen) gekauft.
>
> Ich habe die Sachen von euch (dir, ihnen) gekauft.

Ist es von dem Pronomen abhängig oder haben diese Sätze verschiedene Bedeutungen?

Comment: Hallo @Barkas, was genau meinst du mit der Frage "Ist **es** von dem Pronomen abhängig"?

Answer (score 2):

Die Auswahl der Präposition hat mit dem Pronomen überhaupt nichts zu tun.

"Von" wird verwendet, wenn man direkt eine Person meint, von der man  die Ware gekauft hat - Der Geschäftspartner war eine Person. "von" bezieht sich auf den "Aushändiger".

"Bei" wird verwendet, wenn man eher eine Einrichtung, Firma, Laden oder Gesellschaft meint, die geschäftsmäßig Dinge verkauft. "bei" bezieht sich auf eine Örtlichkeit.

Comment: Oh, ich würde _Sachen von_ eher so interpretieren, dass sie von einem Hersteller, Designer oder Besitzer waren. “Ich habe die Sachen von Calvin Klein gekauft“ heißt für mich nicht, dass Calvin Klein sie mir persönlich übergeben hat. Das was du meinst, würde ich eher mit _etwas (von) jemandem **ab**kaufen_ ausdrücken.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ein "Hersteller, Designer oder Besitzer" ist doch eine Person?

Comment: Wegen des Wortes _direkt_ dachte ich, du hättest gemeint, dass die Person dann auch gleichzeitig der Verkäufer wäre.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ist sie ja dann in übertragenem Sinne auch...